# CakePHP: Setting up ACL allow/deny not working (tables not being updated)?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, acl, cakephp-1.2

I am trying to set up my ACL with the following action in my UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('*');


    }

    function install() {
        $group =& $this->User->Group;

        //Allow admins to everything
        $group->id = 1;     
        $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

        //allow users
        $group->id = 2;
        $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
        $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Messages');
        $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/MessageLists');
        $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Products');
        $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgetviews');
    }
```

So I follow `localhost/users/install`, and after echoing some numbers in the function, I realized it ran. However, Cake gives me the following error:

```
Error: The requested address '/users/install' was not found on this server.
```

I don't really know what the problem is, but my acos/aros/aros_acos tables are all untouched after this. Here is their data from the following query:

```
mysql> select * from aros_acos a join acos c on a.aco_id=c.id join aros r on a.a
ro_id=r.id
    -> ;
+----+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
| id | aro_id | aco_id | _create | _read | _update | _delete | id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias       | lft  | rght | id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias | lft  | rght |
+----+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 | 1       | 1     | 1       | 1       |  1 |      NULL | NULL  |        NULL | controllers |    1 |    2 |  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    4 |
|  2 |      2 |      1 | -1      | -1    | -1      | -1      |  1 |      NULL | NULL  |        NULL | controllers |    1 |    2 |  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    5 |   10 |
|  3 |      1 |      2 | 1       | 1     | 1       | 1       |  2 |      NULL | NULL  |        NULL | controllers |    3 |    4 |  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    4 |
|  4 |      2 |      2 | -1      | -1    | -1      | -1      |  2 |      NULL | NULL  |        NULL | controllers |    3 |    4 |  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    5 |   10 |
+----+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------------+------+------+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:
I had debug set to 0, so after switching it to 2 I am getting the following warnings:

```
Warning (512): AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array
(
    [Aro0.model] => Group
    [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1
)
" [CORE\cake\libs\model\db_acl.php, line 191]
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 324]
Warning (512): AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array
(
    [Aro0.model] => Group
    [Aro0.foreign_key] => 2
)
" [CORE\cake\libs\model\db_acl.php, line 191]
```

I also re-created my DbAcl and it populated the `acos` table but not the `aros` or `aros_acos` tables. The warning above is what I am getting trying to run the `install` action again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create the ACOs for controllers/Messages etc before you you can assign permissions.

Set your debug level to 2 in `app/config/core.php` to get better error messages. The "production" setting makes Cake give the same message for every error.

Comment: i must've turned it off on friday :\ i've updated my post with the warnings.

Comment: it was my bad - i just had to recreate the groups and users after i recreated the DbAcl so that they would register as AROs. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this command:

../cake/console/cake acl create aro root Groups

../cake/console/cake acl create aro root Group.1

../cake/console/cake acl create aro root Group.2

../cake/console/cake acl create aro root Group.3