# Cakehp Acl 'Aro0.foreignKey' in 'where clause''

Tags: php, cakephp

I have problem with Acl in cakePhp 2.5.x . I have done everything cakephp cookbook told me, but i still have a problem.

So I set up my application to have 3 groups. Administrator, Manager, and User, just like in cookbook. 
At this time my app only has 1 user and this user belong to Administrator. Administrator can do anything.

this is my AppController code :

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect'  => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action'     => 'index'
                ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action'     => 'login'
                ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form'      => array(
                        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                    )

                ),
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath'=>'controllers'),
                ),

            )
    );

public function beforeFilter(){
    //not thinked yet
    parent::beforeFilter();
    //$this->initDB();
}

public function initDB(){
    $group = $this->User->MemberOf;
    // Allow admins to everything 
    $group->id = 1; 
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

}
```

}

and UsersController

class UsersController extends AppController{

```
public $helpers     = array('Html','Form');
public $uses        = array("User","Group");

// callbacks
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
```

The problem is when i(Administrator, and i've logged in) want to call 'add' action of UsersController cakephp give me this error :

```
Database Error
```

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Aro0.foreignKey' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Aro`.`id`, `Aro`.`parent_id`, `Aro`.`model`, `Aro`.`foreign_key`, `Aro`.`alias` FROM `dotcore`.`aros` AS `Aro` INNER JOIN `dotcore`.`aros` AS `Aro0` ON (`Aro`.`lft` <= `Aro0`.`lft` AND `Aro`.`rght` >= `Aro0`.`rght`) WHERE `Aro0`.`model` = 'Group' AND `Aro0`.`foreignKey` = '1' ORDER BY `Aro`.`lft` DESC

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

I know that in aros table there's no foreignKey field, but foreign_key, but why cakephp use foreignKey in where clause?

Please help me to solve this problem, i can't find any post/question about this problem, so i ask this problem here.
I really appreciate your response. Thank you

Comment: what happends in the model of aros?

Comment: We at the same time I have the same problem. Look at this answer, do the same for the user  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17382831/1127933

Comment: Nothing changes in model of aros @Widrogo ,

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key in aro used to associate with your groups and users table.

Depending on model column value in aro ,foreign_key treated differently

example :
model = Group : Then the foreign_key is associated with groups table.
model = User : Then the foreign_key is associated with users table.

groups:

```
id    name
1     Administrator
2     Manager
3     User
```

the above column 'id' is treated as a foreign key in aro but mention Model=Group.
if Model= 'User' in aro then foreign key will be user id.

the foreign_key column used to check the permissions by ACL

Example:

```
$this->ACL->check('Group.1',$aco)
```

above method  check for administrator permission on aco.

```
$this->ACL->check('User.1',$aco)
```

above method check permission of user whose  id is  1 on aco.